# Azure Function app is deplying without errors, functions are missing from portal

Tags: typescript, azure-functions

I have created through the Azure VSC extension an Azure function app in TS using `Node 18` and `Azure v4`. The functions defined within work properly when debugging local and I am getting expected results.

Through the extension I have also deployed the Function app to the Azure portal which is deploying without errors. KUDU on diagnostics console for the app shows that the `.ts` file containing the functions are within, they are missing from the portal however and I have yet to find a log which points to an error.

Redeploying, creating a new function app, creating a completely separate function app (different codebase) and still not able to get functions to deploy on the portal.

Adding various configurations on the app's portal such as `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 0` and `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true` (although I read somewhere this is Linux specific) have made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the .ts file I suspect you are not uploading the built / transpiled app but the TypeScript files that you're editing. Unlike js you first need to build the app as TypeScript cannot be run directly.

The Azure Functions Core Tools will do that automatically when you publish the app:

```
func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I probably should have mentioned it above as well, I am able to see the JS transpiled files in dist as well as the TS files. I ran the command per your suggestion and it deployed once again successfully but it ended with this line: "Functions in <functionNameDeducted>":  which leads me to believe its once again not picking up on the functions

Comment: only the contents of dist should be uploaded to the function root, if you're seeing anything else somethings wrong with the deployment

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here later, it seems this was the Sharp library that was causing this. There have been no errors in the build or runtime logs to indicate this, just trial and error and running out of options. Def something I am keeping in mind to have a look at first if the same comes up